# Set focus on input text with PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I currently have an .xhtml that shows a pop up depending on some events in JAVA, now  i need that if the pop up shows put the focus on a expecific textfield.

JAVA

```
public void validate(){
   if(List.size()>0){
    String [] codes = {"1","97","119","606","695","700","738","730"};
    List<String> codesList = Arrays.asList(codes);
    String coomentsString ="THIS IS A STRING";
    if(codesList.contains(List.get(0).getCode())){
        MessageUtil.addInfoMessage(LabelKeys.DOCBR_INFO,coomentsString);
        PrimefacesUtil.showMessage();
    }
   }
}
```

XHTML

```
<p:commandButton id="loadPage" action="#CLASS.validate}"/>
<p:inputText id="comments"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var name= document.getElementById('containerForm:loadPage');
    name.click();
  });
</script>
```

XHTML POP UP

```
<p:dialog id="growl" widgetVar="messagePopupWidget"  resizable="false"
 modal="true" width="270px" styleClass="messagedialog">
    <p:ajax event="close" update="growl" 
      listener="#{messageDialog.handleCloseDialogMessageEvent}" />
        <p:panelGrid style="width:100%;">
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:left;">
                    <p:messages showSummary="true" showDetail="true" 
                      autoUpdate="false" escape="false"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:commandButton id="messageDialogButtonId" value="#{label['messageDialog.btn.ok']}" onclick="messagePopupWidget.hide();" update="growl" type="button"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
```

now, i need that after loadPage makes the click on javascript and shows the pop up from validate(), put the cursor on "comments"

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to achieve this with primefaces:
1. Include this in your dialog to set explicit focus

```
<p:focus for="commentsID"/>
```

2. There is an onShow attribute on the dialog, you can use that to set the focus manually

   `<p:dialog id="loadPage" 
     onShow="document.getElementById("commentsID").focus();"/>`